# output SoX synthesized sound to file

Tags: sound, files, output, sox

I have the following SoX command that generates a nifty 'spacecraft' sound:

```
play -n -c1 synth whitenoise band -n 100 20 band -n 50 20 gain +25  fade h 1 864000 1
```

How could I output about 10 seconds of this to a sound file? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
play -n -c1 synth 10 whitenoise band -n 100 20 band -n 50 20 gain +25  fade h 1 10 1
```

Insert the total duration after *synth* (in this case 10 seconds )
Also supply the duration to *fade* so this function can apply the fade-out time (1 second in this example) at the right moment (i.e. at the ending of the track)

If you want to record this, just do:

```
sox -c1 -n result.wav synth 10 whitenoise band -n 100 20 band -n 50 20 gain +25  fade h 1 10 1
```

This will dump the resulting sound in *result.wav*.